# Saving cyclamen frozen in pots outside?

Tags: houseplants, containers, temperature

I have large cyclamen in pots on my south facing balcony. This morning, thanks to 'The Beast From The East' (extremely cold weather), they are frozen in their pots and drooping, what is my best line of action?

Answer (score 3):

I would do nothing. Cyclamens should resist to freeze. Maybe you could keep near the wall, but I would not bring them inside: too much shock. The cold storm should end soon, so the plant will "defrozen" slowly.

Now you cannot do much. Next year, try to cover them with some tissues. Wait 2 3 weeks, and let see if you plant is still alive. I think so, leaves are hard, possibly it will not flower this year (or just late).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the species/cultivar of cyclamen, it may or may not be resistant to freezing temperatures.

What you can do:  Place it in a sheltered spot where it won’t freeze/thaw too quickly, and wit for new growth (once it thaws, you can check the bulb.. if it’s mushy, you can discard it)

Don’t bring a frozen plant indoors and thaw to room temperature quickly, as this can further damage the cell walls.